# How to add new column when create a csv file in scala

Tags: java, scala, csv

```
val csv_writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(dest+"whatever"+".csv")))

for (x <-storeTimestamp ) {
  csv_writer.write(x + "\n")
}
csv_writer.close()
```

Is there any other ways to write 2 lists of string to a csv file?
For now in my code, I only wrote 1 list of string to the csv file. How to add a new column from another list?
Is it OK to use `Bufferedwriter`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, you have some CSV data and you want to add a new column of data to the end of each line before writing it to a file.

Here's how I might go about it.

```
// some pretend data
val origCSV = Seq("a,b,c", "d,e,f", "x,y,z")
val newCLMN = Seq("4X", "2W", "9A")

// put them together
val allData = origCSV.zip(newCLMN).map{case (a,b) => s"$a,$b\n"}
```

Note: `zip` will only zip the two collections together until it runs out of one or the other. It there's data left in the larger collection then it is ignored. If that's not desirable then you might try `zipAll`.

On to the file writing.

```
import java.io.{File, FileWriter}
import util.Try

val writer = Try(new FileWriter(new File("filename.csv")))
writer.map{w => w.write(allData.mkString); w}
      .recoverWith{case e => e.printStackTrace(); writer}
      .map(_.close())
```

And the result is...

```
>> cat filename.csv
a,b,c,4X
d,e,f,2W
x,y,z,9A
>>
```

Comment: yes! both of my collections are in the same size. thank you for the help. but what happen if they are not the same size? is the solution still valid? or i need to use different approach to write a csv file.

Comment: If the collections are not the same size, and you have rules for what to fill in when one of the collections runs empty, then use `zipAll()` in place of `zip()`.